# React Context Globally with useContext hook

Tags: javascript, reactjs, use-context

I'm a bit confused about how the useContext hook is supposed to work in a "global" state sense.

Here is my App.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import Login from './Components/auth/Login';
import './App.css';
import AuthState from './Context/auth/AuthState';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import Dashboard from './Components/dashboard/DashBoard';
import CollectionState from './Context/collection/CollectionState';
import Collection from './Components/collection/Collection';
import PrivateRoute from './routing/PrivateRoute';
import AddCollectionItem from './Components/collection/AddCollectionItem';
import AddUser from './Components/Users/AddUser';
import Settings from './Components/admin/Settings';

function App() {
  return (
    <AuthState>
</AuthState>
```

And here are the import and setup statements from one of my child components:

```
import React, { useContext, useEffect } from 'react';
import { Route, Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';
import AuthContext from '../Context/auth/authContext';
import Loading from '../utils/Loading';
import Can from '../Components/auth/Can';

const PrivateRoute = ({ component: Component, ...rest }) => {
  const authContext = useContext(AuthContext);
  const { isAuthenticated, loading, user } = authContext;
  const { type, perform } = rest;
  useEffect(() => {
    authContext.loadUser();
    // eslint-disable-next-line
  }, []);
```

My AuthContext is returning AuthContext.Provider from setup.

```
 <AuthContext.Provider
      value={{
        token: state.token,
        isAuthenticated: state.isAuthenticated,
        loading: state.loading,
        user: state.user,
        error: state.error,
        register,
        loadUser,
        login,
        logout,
        clearErrors,
      }}
    >
      {props.children}
    </AuthContext.Provider>
  );
};
```

Basically - I'm using the AuthContext to provide basic front end validation for components, and then verifying that validation with the backend.

The issue is when I am using the useContext hook in a child component, it is creating a duplicate context within the child component. Since I am using this for component validation, it would be helpful to have the methods accessible within the child components, so I can return different portions of it based on user access, etc.

Is there a way to access the global context without instantiating a new context inside child components? I'm using this context template from a tutorial I followed, and while I understand the concept of useContext, I seem to be missing a key component here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to read data from a "global" context, you need to be under a Provider instance. If you're not, consuming a context in a child component will create a new instance of that context and return you its default data.

I'm making an assumption here, because I don't know your entire components tree, but: it looks like you didn't wrap your app in the context provider. So you might want to have something like this:

```
import AuthContext from '../Context/auth/authContext';

function App() {
  return (
    <AuthContext>
      <AuthState>
        {/* ... */}
      </AuthState>
    </AuthContext>
  );
}
```

Comment: Hey Andrei - thanks. I think I actually figured out the question I had. I'm using the useContext hook, which according to the docs is an alternative to using context.consumer.

My Authstate component is actually returning AuthContext.Provider as a child component, so its a bit hidden in my code, but it seems thats taken care of. Much appreciate your time and effort answering.

Answer (score 0):

I think I actually figured out the question I had. I'm using the useContext hook, which according to the docs is an alternative to using context.consumer. My Authstate component is actually returning AuthContext.Provider as a child component, so its a bit hidden in my code, but it seems thats taken care of. Much appreciate your time and effort answering.